# How to upgrade npm and node? How to install n?

Tags: node.js, npm

From here http://theholmesoffice.com/node-js-fundamentals-how-to-upgrade-the-node-js-version/ i am trying to upgade my 'node' and 'npm'.

For this i need to install 'n';

But with `sudo npm install -g n`

I get error :

```
Error : failed to fetch from registry: n
```

How to resolve this problem and upgrade npm and node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`?
and you should have mentioned your current version of node and npm